# Javascript map/filter/reduce over facebook messenger data

Tags: javascript, array, json

Context: I am making a website that allows people to upload their Facebook Messenger data, and see data visualizations for conversations. It is a React front-end, and a nodejs back-end. It doesn't store anything in a database at the moment, but there is a caching layer to deal with different sessions. So once the user uploads their facebook messenger data, the nodejs back-end is supposed to crunch the numbers and aggregate different statistics.

The json looks like:

```
{
  "participants": [{"name":"Adam"}, {"name":"Bob"}, {"name":"Chris"}],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Adam",
      "timestamp_ms": 1533332999910,
      "content": "I am editing my stackexchange question right now",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Bob",
      "timestamp_ms": 1533332999910,
      "content": "Okay, good luck",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ],
  "title": "High School Friends",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "RegularGroup",
  "thread_path": "inbox/highschoolfriends__aAe4vb"
}
```

`messages` is an array of objects, with common text messages having the shape of the above, with other fields that are optional like photos, audio_files, etc.

To compute the set up the data I use:

```
let jsonMessages = require('../analytics/message_1.json');

let participants = jsonMessages.participants;
let messages = jsonMessages.messages;

let people =  participants.map(function(person) {
    return person.name;
});
```

So now the data is a javascript object.

So my question: Am I missing something obvious about the **map/filter/reduce** powers by doing a big for loop of filters? Would this pass code review for an internal analytics tool?

Here is what I have tried:

```
let people = ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Chris', 'Dave'];

people.forEach(function (person) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = person;
    obj.messageCount = messages.filter((obj) => obj.sender_name === person).length;

    obj.photoMessageCount = messages.filter((obj) => ((obj.sender_name === person) && ((obj.photos != null) )).length;

    obj.videoGifMessageCount = messages.filter((obj) => ((obj.sender_name === person) && ((obj.gifs !=null) || (obj.videos!= null))).length;

    obj.audioMessageCount = messages.filter((obj) => ((obj.sender_name === person) && (obj.audio_files != null))).length;

    obj.richContentMessageCount = obj.photoMessageCount + obj.videoGifMessageCount + obj.audioMessageCount;

    stats.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big inefficiency of the initial approach is that for each `person` (which is actually a *person's name*) `messages` collection will be traversed **4** times.

To significantly optimize the traversal algorithm the current one is substituted with a ***single*** loop with multiple conditions per iteration.
All the needed specific *counts* are declared beforehand and used as *accumulators*.
The *Consolidate conditional expression* technique is applied based on a common condition `m.sender_name === personName`.

The final optimized version:

```
people.forEach((personName) => {
    let stat = {'name': personName, 'messageCount': 0, 'photoMessageCount': 0, 
               'videoGifMessageCount': 0, 'audioMessageCount': 0};
    messages.forEach((m) => {
        if (m.sender_name === personName) { 
            stat.messageCount++;
            if (m.photos) stat.photoMessageCount++;
            if (m.gifs || m.videos) stat.videoGifMessageCount++;
            if (m.audio_files) stat.audioMessageCount++;
        }
    });
    stat.richContentMessageCount = stat.photoMessageCount + stat.videoGifMessageCount 
                                   + stat.audioMessageCount;
    stats.push(stat);
});
```

---

In case if your `stats` array is intended to be used only for accumulating statistics from `people.forEach(...)` iterated once - prefer [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) approach to create `stats` array with the results at once:

```
let stats = people.map((personName) => {
    let stat = {'name': personName, 'messageCount': 0, 'photoMessageCount': 0, 
               'videoGifMessageCount': 0, 'audioMessageCount': 0};
    // all the logic here
    // ...
    return stat;
});
```